# Getting question marks using Python requests with Excel file

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to Python3 and requests. I found a Dataset on *Harvard Dataverse* but I've been stuck for hours trying to extract the Dataset. Instead I get question marks in my content and no readable data. I found similar issues but I'm still unable to solve mine.

Can anyone help me please ?
It would be so much appreciated ;)

Many thanks !!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
#print(sys.executable)
#print(sys.version)
#print(sys.version_info)

url = "https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/5856951"

r = requests.get(url)
print(type(r))
print('*************')
print('Response Code:', r.status_code)
print('*************')
print('Response Headers:\n', r.headers)
print('*************')
print('Response Content:\n',r.text)
print(r.encoding)
print(r.content)


with open('myfile.csv', mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(r.text)

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
print("The content of the file is:\n", data)
print(data.head(10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the request URL is not giving valid json response instead it is returning the whole excel file that contains the dataset which you want.

Instead of directly accessing the response object you should first save the response in excel file 'dataset.xlsx' then try to access that excel file in order to get results which you want.

The following code will help you to save the response in excel file. Then you can use xlrd https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/ python library to extract data from the file.

```
url = "https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/5856951"
resp = requests.get(url)
open('dataset.xlsx', 'wb').write(resp.content)
```

Comment: Hello, @asadHussain thank you for your help, I followed your recommandations and I used pandas to get the Data :                                                  `url = "https://dataverse.harvard.edu/api/access/datafile/5856951"
resp = requests.get(url)
open('dataset.xlsx', 'wb').write(resp.content)

xls = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
xls.head(10)`